# Is the quotient of two dense sequences dense?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I was wondering if the quotient of two dense sequences are dense. Since we know that the sequences $a_n = \cos(n)$ and $b_n = \sin(n)$ are both dense from $[-1,1]$, it would be easy to show (if the answer to my question is yes) that the sequence $c_n = \tan(n) = \frac{b_n}{a_n}$ is dense. Does the limit rule for quotient apply for this?

Comment: It would also be easy to show that $\frac{a_n}{a_n}$ is dense, no?

Comment: do you mean $\frac{b_n}{a_n}$?

Comment: No. If $a_n$ is a dense sequence, and if $b_n=a_n,$ then $a_n$ and $b_n$ are both dense sequences, so if the answer to your question is yes, then $a_n/a_n$ is a dense sequence. This seems to be a counterexample. If this isn't what you meant, then maybe you need to state your question more carefully.

Comment: Yeah I see your point, but the sequence that I have given, $\sin(n)$ and $\cos(n)$ are never equal to each other because $n$ is just a natural number. So if $a_n$ and $b_n$ are never equal to each other, does my argument work?

Comment: $a_n=\cos n$ and $b_n=-\cos n$ are never equal to each other.

Comment: Any rearrangement of a dense sequence is dense. If $\{a_n\}$ and $\{b_n\}$ are any two dense sequences of nonzero terms, then you can rearrange them so that the $n^\text{th}$ terms of the two sequences are approximately equal to each other, i.e., the ratio is close to $1.$ So you're not going to be able to prove that $\{\tan n\}$ is dense just from the fact that $\{\sin n\}$ and $\{\cos n\}$ are dense.